# Kriat hatorah simchat torah

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, trop-cantillation, simchat-torah

Why in many ashkenazi communities is the torah reading of simchat torah read with the melody of the yamim noraim?

Comment: Why should it not be? Also how do you know that in many ashkenazi communities that is the practice? Also why do you call the tune "the melody of the yamim noraim" and not "the melody of Rosh HaShana, Yom Kippur and Simchat Torah"? It seems like your whole question is based on your own dubious naming convention.

Comment: well if it is supposed to be used on simchat torah as well as on rosh hashanah and yom hakippurim then what connects them? Also There are places that dont use it on simchat torah and say that it is a yamim noraim trope and not for simchat torah

Comment: You should include your questions in the post, not in comments. If you forgot to write your question in the question originally, there's always the [edit] function. In the future, try not to write questions that are one line long. Those are usually quite poor. Use some more words to make sure you get what you want by being clear.

Comment: Im not so sure I understand what part of my comment you think I should add to my question

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46442&st=&pgnum=442&hilite=) writes that when the Chazzan holds the Sefer Torah, the minhag is to add in the word ונורא to אחד אלהינו, just as one does on Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur.
He then quotes sources that write that the Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur tune is used to call people up.
The Minhag to lein in this tune may have developed from this.

Comment: קדוש ונורא שמו is just the verse in Tehillim https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%90_%D7%98 Omitting the word Nora on certain days when taking out the Torah is a late practice (~300 years old) which was criticized in its infancy and is still not uniformly practiced. See Eliya Rabba. In old texts back to [Masekhet Sofrim](https://www.sefaria.org/Gra's_Nuschah_on_Tractate_Soferim.14.10.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the word Nora is always there with no special note.